# Symmetric Block design

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a non-empty, finite set.

Consider the object $B = \{B_1, \ldots, B_{|A|}\}$ where $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A$, and the $B_i$ are subsets of $A$ with the following properties:

- $|B_i \cap B_j| = 1, \forall i \neq j$
- $|B_i| = \kappa, \forall i$
- $\kappa <|A|$

Show that such a $B$ only exists for sets $A$ with $|A| = n^2 + n + 1$ for an integer $n\geq1$

Comment: I think some precondition is missing. Otherwise, you could always have $B = \emptyset$ or $B = \{C\}$ where $C$ is an arbitrary proper subset of $A$.